# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show and hide several divs based on which button  is clicked but nothing happens and in the Chrome Inspector I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined"

Thanks in advance!

Triggers and block:

```
echo '<button class="more" onClick="toggleLyrics()">Show lyrics <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></button>';
echo '<div class="lyricsBox" style="display: block;"><pre>' . $row['lyrics'] .'</pre></div>';
```

Script:

```
<script>
function toggleLyrics(){
var lyricsMore = document.getElementsByClassName('more');
var lyricsBox = document.getElementsByClassName("lyricsBox");

var displaySetting = lyricsBox.style.display;

if (displaySetting == 'block') { 
  lyricsBox.style.display = 'none';
}
else { 
  lyricsBox.style.display = 'block';
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection that you access by index in order to get the DOM elements found.

You can do this individually:

```
lyricsBox[0].style.display
```

or in a typical `for` loop.

---

Another option, if you only need the first element matched, is to use `querySelector` instead.

```
var lyricsBox = document.querySelector(".lyricsBox");
```

This will return the first element matched by the CSS selector. It also has better browser support than `.getElementsByClassName`.

It has a counterpart `.querySelectorAll()` that returns a collection as well.

Comment: I want to display the div based on which div is clicked (the php code prints several divs), would the for loop do so and if so, what would that for loop look like?

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` return an element collection, you need first get the element from the collection.

```
function toggleLyrics(){
var lyricsMore = document.getElementsByClassName('more');
var lyricsBox = document.getElementsByClassName("lyricsBox");

var displaySetting = lyricsBox[0].style.display;

if (displaySetting == 'block') { 
  lyricsBox[0].style.display = 'none';
}
else { 
  lyricsBox[0].style.display = 'block';
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry that the question might have been unclear but there will be several divs but I only want the specific clicked div to be shown/hidden